# Compression method LZNT on a file

Tags: windows, winapi, compression

If I have a file of size Y bytes, and I apply LZNT1 compression, then how many bytes can I save ? What is the suffix NT1 shortened for ?

Answer (score 0):

As with all lossless compression schemes, the savings from compression are dependent on the contents of the file. Files which contain more redundancy (e.g, repeated sequences of bytes) will compress better than those which do not.

"NT" is probably for "NTFS" or "Windows NT", and "1" is probably to distinguish it from a future LZNT2 algorithm.